# Getting a specific part from a PowerShell command output

Tags: powershell

I am calling the following PowerShell command and assigning the output to a variable:

```
$my_variable = (Get-Counter -Counter "\Process(process1)\Working Set - Private") | Out-String
```

The output is:

```
> Timestamp                 CounterSamples
> ---------                 -------------- 
> 4/7/2015 3:54:00 PM       \\smachine101\process(process1)\working set - private :
>                           15298560
```

All I need is '15298560' from the output.

Can you recommend a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing would be to use `Out-String` with caution. In doing so you have destroyed the object into a string. String manipulation to extract the wanted data is possible but a waste of good PowerShell-ing when the original object contains that data in a property.

You are just looking for the cooked value? This would work in PowerShell 2.0

```powershell
Get-Counter -Counter "\Process(chrome)\Working Set - Private" | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty CounterSamples | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty CookedValue
```

Of course you could write that with aliases and shortened property names but it gives you an idea of what the full command looks like. If you have PowerShell 3.0 you could use dot notation like this

```powershell
(Get-Counter -Counter "\Process(chrome)\Working Set - Private").CounterSamples.CookedValue
```

Using a combination of `Get-Member` and viewing individual properties of objects would have been an approach to figure out this issue.